# Create multi-party channel on behalf of another user (slack API)

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I have an application in which I need to create multi-party im groups in slack, and then provide a url to the user to access the group.

First, user `A` in a given client organization `A_org` registers their license of the app with slack using slacks Oauth2 method.

Later on, user `B` (not the user who originally registered the app / created the auth token), needs to access a multi-party group messaging channel.

Currently, I am creating the group as so:

```
const response = await callSlackApiMethod('mpim.open', {
  token: access_token, // <-- access token of authorizing user (user A)
  users: slackIds.join(',') // <-- group of users including B, not including A
});
```

where `callSlackApiMethod` simply `GET`s the REST method from slack with provided params.

**The Problem:**

The group returned in `response` always includes the slackId of user `A`. Is there a way to create a mpim channel for user B (and other users), not including user A, and without having to seprately authorize each user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible with [mpim.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/mpim.open). Using the token of user A to create the mpim channel is the same as user A inviting other users into a group conversation.

But you can create a new private channel with [groups.create](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.create) instead and invite user B to it. It will also include user A at first, but user A can leave the private channel so that only user B (and any other invited users) remains.

Please note though, that by leaving the private channel with user A you loose control over it in your script. You will not be able to re-enter or manage it in any way. A workaround that I have been using is to have a admin user account (e.g. slackadmin) which can stay in private channel without appearing as a "spying user".

Comment: Thanks for your help, the use of an admin user account might be the best option.